# How to trigger "running state" in Flash Player?

Tags: c++, com, activex, flash

If I use windowed activation (giving a valid `HWND` to the Flash PLayer in the `GetWindow` function is enough to trigger this), the player will run the loaded swf file. However, if I use windowless activation, the loaded file does not run, only the very first frame is displayed. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14673/Transparent-Flash-Control-in-Plain-C) claims that I'm supposed to call

```
DoVerb(OLEIVERB_SHOW, NULL, (IOleClientSite *)this, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

However, this does not have any effect. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Since I made this post, I found out that it returns -2147467259, which is not a known HRESULT, but certainly not 0. What does it mean?

After some more digging I found out that the return value is `OLE_E_NOTRUNNING`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. Before this call, I was doing:

```
hr = _shockwaveFlash->put_WMode(BSTR("opaque"));
```

BUT I blatantly ignored the HRESULT there. It made the Flash Player confused, because it is not a valid way to insert a `BSTR` constant in the code (which is a wide string). Correctly:

```
hr = _shockwaveFlash->put_WMode(L"opaque");
```

Now it works as it should. Check you HRESULTs, kids :)